# PDO simple SELECT - how to handle no results when using foreach

Tags: php, pdo

I am slowly learning PHP and am using PDO.

Looking here:
https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#foreach

It says:

> The most basic and direct way to get multiple rows from a statement would be foreach() loop. Thanks to Traversable interface, PDOStatement can be iterated over by using foreach() operator:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT name FROM users');
foreach ($stmt as $row)
{
    echo $row['name'] . "\n";
}
```

How would I change the code to check for no results, as I can't work out how to do that?

I realise that if the SQL returns no records, the foreach don't output anything, but I would prefer to have some kind of check in place to e.g. echo "No records found".

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I just tested to see and even if the SQL returns no results (e.g. SELECT name FROM users WHERE email = 'sillytest'), if I do a simple check then $stmt = true. It also returns true when the SQL does return data.

Comment: @JayBlanchardL: That’s not correct either …

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you still want to use the `foreach` method, you can set a flag inside the loop, then check for its existence afterward to output your "No records" message.

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT name FROM users');
foreach ($stmt as $row)
{
    echo $row['name'] . "\n";
    $found_rows = true;
}
if (!isset($found_rows)) echo "No records found.";
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need complex code for this. Assuming you have set PDO in exception mode, and you know how to catch errors, your code becomes basically a one liner

```
$results = $pdo->query("SELECT name FROM users")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(count($results)) 
{
    // You have records.
}
```

You can even skip the counting part and go straight into

```
foreach($results as $row) ....
```

If the array is empty, foreach won't do a thing.

Answer (score -2):

```
$sql = 'SELECT name FROM users';

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  // $db is your database connection object from PDO constructor
$stmt->execute();

$res = $stmt->fetchAll();

if ($res) {
    foreach ...
} else {
    // no records
}

    // if (!$res === false) {
        // failure
    // } elseif (count($res) < 1) {
        // no records
    // } else {
       // at least one record
       // loop
    // }
```

Personally I would use prepare() and execute() and fetch()/fetchAll()

Comment: Thanks @MacGyer - how would I use prepare() on a simple SQL which did not contain any parameters? Is prepare only for use with parameterised queries?

Comment: No... you can prepare everything. Might be over the top if no params are present. But what if you have to change the statement during development? I edited the answer